# clone link that contains specific text and append to new li class only when written in the HTML

Tags: jquery

I'm struggling to understand how i can get this accomplished.

Currently in the HTML

```
<td class="welcome" rowspan="3">
    <b>
        27412 Commissioner
    </b>
     (
    <a href="http://football34.myfantasyleague.com/2015/logout?L=27412">
        Logout
    </a>
     | 
    <a href="http://football34.myfantasyleague.com/2015/logout?L=27412&BECOME=0001">
        Become Owner
    </a>
    )
    <br></br>
    <small>
        <a href="http://football34.myfantasyleague.com/2015/support?L=27412&PROGRAM=commissioner_setup" target="_blank">
            Help Center
        </a>
    </small>
</td>
```

I need to have a script that if td.welcome has text  "Become Owner" or "Become Commissioner"  , clone and append that specific a href link and text

Then somewhere esle in the HTML i want to add a new li class called

```
<li class="become"></li>
```

and have the link and text displayed appened to it, so the resulting HTML would look like this

```
<li class="become">
        <a href="http://football34.myfantasyleague.com/2015/logout?L=27412&BECOME=0001">
            Become Owner
        </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Please give us samples of your desired html output.

Comment: What have you performed on JS or JQuery ? How you parse your code ?

Comment: updated to show resulting HTML desired, but want the a class and text appended to the li.become  , so i can simply place that li class and have the link displayed within in. I do not know jquery at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
//Find nodes that contain "Become Owner" or "Become Commissioner" in nodes with the class "welcome"
var $link = $('.welcome :contains("Become Owner"), .welcome :contains("Become Commissioner")'); 

//If we have results
if($link.length > 0){
  //append a clone of the first result to the nodes with the class "become"
  $('.become').append($link[0].cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
      <tr>
        <td class="welcome" rowspan="3">
            <b>
                27412 Commissioner
            </b>
            (
            <a href="http://football34.myfantasyleague.com/2015/logout?L=27412">
                Logout
            </a>
            | 
            <a href="http://football34.myfantasyleague.com/2015/logout?L=27412&BECOME=0001">
                Become Owner
            </a>
            )
            <br></br>
            <small>
                <a href="http://football34.myfantasyleague.com/2015/support?L=27412&PROGRAM=commissioner_setup" target="_blank">
                    Help Center
                </a>
            </small>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<ul>
    <li class="become"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ty Brandon , was searching around and found this also that works, which is better to use , yours or this below  $("li.become").append($("td.welcome a:contains('Become Owner')"));
$("li.become").append($("td.welcome a:contains('Become Commissioner')"));

Comment: Those selectors are a bit more specific as they're limiting to `li`, `td`, and `a` nodes in addition to the `class` and `:contains` selectors. It could be more reliable if you're expecting the classes `become` and `welcome` to exist on different types of nodes. Also, this code will not `clone` the node it finds, it will actually remove it from its original location and place it within the `li.become` node. So you'll still need to call `cloneNode` so the link shows up in both places.